# How to change youtube video's player settings using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am writing a simple Chrome extension to change the speed of a video on youtube. [The code can be found here.](https://github.com/pranavsingh/fastertube)

In essence, I am using the following code to change the speed:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2;
```

This works well, but doesn't affect the settings on the player. Which also cause some issues, especially when you switch videos.

Is there a better approach to interact directly with the player?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Youtube Player API iframe embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls), *Iframe API* allows you to control the speed of the video.

The default playback rate is 1, which indicates that the video is playing at normal speed. Playback rates may include values like 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2.

Here is a sample code for Iframe API:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var player;
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
        events: {
            'onReady': function(e){
                // e.target = player
                e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
                e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
            },
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this create a new player?